# Terminal letters all white and unable to use la e l commands

Tags: laravel, terminal, composer-php

I was trying to install laravel and composer and when i tried to change $PATH somehow letters turned white and being unable to use commands like cd or ls but somehow i put those working but still i cant use commands like `la` or `l` ,and i don't what other commands i can't use either, and most of all i can't still use command `laravel new` saying composer.phar is missing.

`whereis composer.phar` command output:

```
composer: /usr/bin/composer /usr/share/man/man1/composer.1.gz
```

`laravel new pr1` command output:

```
Crafting application...
Could not open input file: composer.phar
Application ready! Build something amazing.
```

`echo $PATH` output

```
/home/alexandre/.config/composer/vendor/bin:/home/alexandre/.config/composer/vendor/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

`type composer` output

```
composer is /usr/bin/composer
```

`which composer` output

```
/usr/bin/composer
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to fix your `$PATH` variable. Run `echo $PATH` and check what system paths are output. You should see `/usr/bin`, `/usr/local/bin`, `/bin`, etc. etc.

Which OS are you using? You can trying running `type composer` or `which composer` to get the install path, but I would imagine it's not going to work with a broken env $PATH .

Comment: tks for the help, and and the commands `type composer` and `which composer` did work

Comment: Not a problem, I would next run `source ~/.bashrc` to try and reset your session state.

Comment: i ran that command `source ~/.bashrc` and `laravel new pr` still is the same `laravel new pwq
Crafting application...
Could not open input file: composer.phar
Application ready! Build something amazing.`

Comment: but if i ran this command `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog` it still works tho :/

Comment: Ok, maybe a symlink will fix this: `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer.phar`. That should get it to recognize the composer executable.

Comment: still `Crafting application...
Could not open input file: composer.phar
Application ready! Build something amazing.` but if i ran it again it gives me In `NewCommand.php line 99:
  Application already exists!`

Comment: `cd pr`  output:       `app    composer.json  database public    server.php  webpack.mix.js
artisan    composer.lock  package.json resources  storage     yarn-error.log
bootstrap  config   phpunit.xml routes    tests`

Comment: Which file did you edit initially to change the $PATH?

Comment: $HOME/.config/composer/vendor/bin for laravel

Comment: all thought i dont remenber exactly the command but it was something like this ` echo 'export "$PATH=$HOME/.config/composer/vendor/bin for laravel"'

Comment: Ah, you need to append `$PATH` on the end there: `export PATH="$HOME/.config/composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"`

Comment: `/home/alexandre/.config/composer/vendor/bin:/home/alexandre/.config/composer/vendor/bin:/home/alexandre/.config/composer/vendor/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin=/home/alexandre/.config/composer/vendor/bin:/home/alexandre/.config/composer/vendor/bin:/home/alexandre/.config/composer/vendor/bin:/home/alexandre/.config/composer/vendor/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin': not a valid identifier

Comment: it gave me this :/

Comment: I botched the export, it should be: `export PATH="$HOME/.config/composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"

Comment: Oh good deal! You probably want to include `$HOME/.config/composer/vendor/bin` in `$PATH` export of your `.bashrc` file so it persists across sessions and reboots.